# Linq include nested collection and orderby

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have nested entities like Property -> Facility -> Farm -> License etc.

I want to get the most recent license and my original query looks like this.

```
return _db.Properties
                .Include(c => c.Contact)
                .Include(f => f.Facilities.Select(c => c.Contact))
                .Include(f => f.Facilities.Select(ff => ff.Farms.Select(s => s.Species)))
                .Include(x => x.Facilities.Select(l => l.Licenses))
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropertyID == id);
```

Since I want to get the most recent license I tried

```
   return _db.Properties
                .Include(c => c.Contact)
                .Include(f => f.Facilities.Select(c => c.Contact))
                .Include(f => f.Facilities.Select(ff => ff.Farms.Select(s => s.Species)))
                .Include(x => x.Facilities.Select(l => l.Licenses.OrderByDescending(d => d.IssueDate)))
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropertyID == id);
```

which fails of course because you cant use an orderby clause there.

If I try an orderby clause at the end of the linq it will start at Property and I will need to drill down to the licenses again.

What is the preferred convention for this?

--EDIT--
Based on Robert's suggestion I flipped the query to get the Licenses first but I guess I need to do some projection since this query only gives me the Property entity and no child entities.

```
  return  _db.Licenses.OrderByDescending(x => x.IssueDate)
                .Include(f => f.Facility)
                .Include(f => f.Facility.Property)
                .Include(f => f.Facility.Property.Contact)
                .Include(c => c.Facility.Contact)
                .Include(f => f.Facility.Farms)
                .Include(f => f.Facility.Farms.Select(s => s.Species))
                .Where(x => x.Facility.Property.PropertyID == id)
                .Select(x => x.Facility.Property).SingleOrDefault();
```

Any ideas to get all children?

Comment: Maybe this works? `_db.Properties.OrderByDescending(x => x.Facilities.Max(f => f.Licenses.Max(l => l.IssueDate)))` Not sure what EF is going to make out of that though

Comment: `Include` cannot be used to load filtered data - it's all or nothing. It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve with that `OrderBy` though. The `DbSet`s and collection type navigation properties are unordered by definition.

Comment: Ivan, I am trying to get the most recent license based on the IssueDate of the license for each facility.

Comment: You can't do that with `Include` - read the first comment and also a lot of similar posts on SO. You either load ALL licenses (unordered) or none.

Comment: If you only want the latest license, you should probably start with the `_db.Licenses` and grab all the relevant information for them rather than starting from Properties.  If you really want the Properties, but you only really want the latest License, you really can't do that easily.  You will need to come up with a custom POCO object, fill it from the db, then you can go back and load the Licenses in a separate query.

Comment: Andres, Add your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted solution.